# What CSS Framework does StackOverflow use?

Tags: discussion, design

I am in charge of maintaining a large number of sites running on the same code base but with subtle color/ui differences. This is similar to how Stack Overflow has many different Q&A sites with the same code base but different layouts/colors. I remember reading an Article written by one of the Stack Overflow founders where he praised a CSS framework that made managing multiple sites with similar layouts a lot easier for him. I've always wanted to investigate that framework, but forgot to bookmark the article. Does this ring a bell to anyone?

Comment: There is an article on Meta about the technology used to build the site.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin, the article doesn't mention the css framework this post is about.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for "core", but on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com) we use [less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/). This lets us have a few files which just define colors/images etc - the main template uses the variables.

For the scenario you ask about, I think it makes perfect sense.

Comment: How do you integrate a ruby library with all the .NET technology used elsewhere?  Or is chat written in ruby?

Comment: @Sam - there are .NET versions. And actually we run it in a script at build time anyway, so *any* version would be fine.

Comment: @Sam - I fixed the link for you ;p

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.